# Component height 100% in Angular 2

Tags: css, angular

The give example is based on the default Angular 2 skeleton created by `ng init`.

Lets assume I want my main component to fill the entire screen with a blue background.

**app.component.css**:

```
my_component_div {
    background-color:lightblue;
    height:100%;
}
```

(global) **styles.css**:

```
html, body {
    height: 100%;
    margin:0; padding:0;
}
```

This is the result:

[image: visible_scrollbar]

I do not want a scroll bar. I don't like scroll bars. Why is there a scroll bar? Why is there a white border on top? According to inspection ([see screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bvwn2.png)), this padding-margin-something in the top is *outside of body*, yet *inside of html*. How can this totally basic functionality be achieved?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because, by deafult, your angular component is using a `<h1>app works!</h1>`

browser has some built in default CSS which gives your H1 a margin of .67em

```
h1 {
display: block;
font-size: 2em;
-webkit-margin-before: 0.67em;
-webkit-margin-after: 0.67em;
-webkit-margin-start: 0px;
-webkit-margin-end: 0px;
font-weight: bold;
}
```

try setting the h1 margin to 0 and your body will re-align with your window.

```
h1 {
    margin:0;
    padding: 0.67em 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Maybe

```
my_component_div {
    background-color:lightblue;
    height:100vh;
}

html, body {
    height: 100vh;
    margin:0; 
    padding:0;
    overflow: auto;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to try to use Reset css as mentioned in the below link-
A CSS Reset, often compressed (minified) set of CSS rules that resets the styling of all HTML elements to a consistent baseline.

http://cssreset.com/what-is-a-css-reset/